# Strange behavior Console.WriteLine() with SystemEvents

Tags: c#, console, system

The Console.WriteLine() does not output anything to the screen, while the handler SystemEvents_SessionSwitch() is called in blocking computer. But if in the Main() method call at least once the method Console.WriteLine(), then the method in the handler will work. What is the reason for this strange behavior / bug?

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit, .NET Framework 4.0

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace TestWindowsEvents
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
             //Console.WriteLine("Test"); //if uncomment this line, then Console.WriteLine() in SystemEvents_SessionSwitch() will work
             Console.ReadKey();
         }

         static void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("SessionSwitch"); //this does not working 
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SessionSwitchDebug"); //and this does not working too..
         }
    }
}
```

**Updated:**
The handler itself SystemEvents_SessionSwitch () is called. I specifically checked this by putting a breakpoint. And after locking computer breakpoint activated. But Console.WriteLine() does not output any text to console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell from the description of the problem that you are using .NET 4.5.  Your Console.ReadKey() method takes a lock, new behavior in 4.5, it prevents other threads from writing to the console and mess up the display.

That lock prevents your event handler from writing to the console.  It runs on another thread, necessary because you are using a console mode program that doesn't pump a message loop.  The SystemEvents class will create its own to ensure the events fire.  The upvoted answer is wrong about that.

What it tries to write does eventually make it to the console, but that of course happens a millisecond before the console window closes so you never see it.

This new 4.5 behavior does spell doom to quicky programs to test something.  You'll need a better way to decide that your program is done, the "Hit any key to continue" method doesn't work so well anymore.  A rather lame alternative that doesn't take the lock could be:

```
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
```

---

UPDATE: this problem was fixed in a .NET 4.5 update delivered through Windows Update.  Not exactly sure when I got the update, somewhere around August 2013.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really works! But the strange thing is that I actually use the fourth version, not 4.5. I just got it checked again by going to the project properties.

Comment: You can't use the "forth version" when you also have 4.5 installed.  4.5 overwrites 4.0.  Targeting 4.0 in your project only stops you from accidentally using classes that are not available in 4.5

Comment: Thanks. I do not know about it.

Answer (score 2):

The event is simply not called. In your check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionswitch.aspx), it says:

> This event is only raised if the message pump is running. In a Windows
>   service, unless a hidden form is used or the message pump has been
>   started manually, this event will not be raised.

Comment: In fact of the matter is that called. I specifically checked this by putting a breakpoint in handler. And after locking computer breakpoint activated. But Console.WriteLine() does not output any text to console...

Comment: This MSDN note is not very accurate.  SystemEvents will start its own thread *and* pump a message loop if the main thread of a program isn't suitable to get the job done.  The apartment state of the thread matters, it is MTA in a C# console mode app.  Also why the OP saw that the event actually fired.  He's got a different problem.